# Extracting function call list from DOxygen XML Output

Tags: doxygen

I posted a [question](https://sourceforge.net/projects/doxygen/forums/forum/130994/topic/3875842) on the DOxygen forums and also am posting it here for a better response.

I have a moderately sized C project of about 2,900 functions.  I am using DOxygen 1.5.9 and it is successfully generating a call graph for the functions.  Is there a way to extract this out for further analysis?  A simple paired list would be sufficient, e.g.

```
Caller,Callee
FunctionX, FunctionY
...
```

I am comfortable with XSLT but I must say that the DOxygen XML output is complex.  Has anyone done this before and can provide some guidance on how to parse the XML files?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to use XSLT specifically, or are you coding for any other language like C or C#? Also, you should post a sample of the Doxygen XML output here if you want to receive more accurate suggestions.

Comment: It isn't necessary to use XSLT; I could use something else.  The question isn't really about how to parse XML - I know how to do that.  It's more basic - how does DOxygen organize its (many) XML output files and how can I establish the caller - callee relationship from them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on what I see in the contrived example that I created,

- Parse files with a name similar to `^_(.+)\d+(c|cpp|h|hpp)\.xml$`, if my regex-foo is right.
- Find all `<memberdef kind="function">`. It has a unique `id` attribute. I believe the XPath for this is `//memberdef[@kind='function']`.
- Within that element, find all `<references>`.
- For each of those tags, the `refid` attribute uniquely refers to the `id` attribute of the corresponding `<memberdef>` that is being called.
- The text node within each `<references>` corresponds to the `<name>` of the corresponding `<memberdef>` that is being called.

This seems like a nice, straightforward way to express call graphs. You should have no trouble using XSLT or any other sane XML-parsing suite to get the desired results.