# Can I extract function arguments from a function pointer?

Tags: c++, scripting, function-pointers

Can I extract extra information (like number of arguments and their types) from a function pointer? If (most likely) not, what is the best way to allow a programmer to pass in a function pointer and the <strike>variable number of arguments</strike> `EDIT: I meant that it should allow functions with different number of arguments` that it takes while making sure that the programmer does not pass incorrect argument types.

**What I want to do:**
Expose functions and its arguments to scripting language without having a programmer to type the arguments out manually (and therefore allowing mistakes to occur where the programmer passes the function pointer and the incorrect arguments that the function takes in).

**A little more clarification:** I should be able to output the function name and the argument types for documentation purposes.

-----------------  **SOLUTION** -----------------

James's answer is what I was looking for. Here is the code as it is a *bit* convoluted that should help anybody stuck in the same situation.

```
boost::function_traits<boost::remove_pointer
                         <BOOST_TYPEOF(&SomeFunction)>::type>::arg2_type);
```

If you require output, use RTTI (assuming you have RTTI enabled in compiler)

```
std::cout << typeid(boost::function_traits<boost::remove_pointer
    <BOOST_TYPEOF(&SomeFunction)>::type>::arg2_type).name() << std::endl;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "variable number of arguments"?  Do you mean that some functions will have variadic arguments or that different functions will have different numbers of arguments.

Comment: You must call a function (pointer) with the correct number of arguments at compile-time.  What you are describing doesn't make sense.

Comment: @David: That different functions will have different number of arguments

Comment: @Oli: The approach described may be a little incoherent, but the expressed goal makes perfect sense, at least to me.  Ever called WinAPI (or any native DLL) functions from VB or .NET, you have to generate matching declarations that describe the function to import including all parameters.  He seems to want to do this automatically from the C++ type information.

Comment: @Ben: My impression is that he/she wants to be able to dynamically call arbitrary functions at run-time.

Comment: @Oli: Yes, and it's a solved problem in many scripting environments, as long as the type information is provided (often as a string, but that's far from the ideal representation).  The key seems to be that neither the C++ nor script developer should have to manually keep this metadata in sync with the C++ code being called, it should happen automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the arity, return type, and parameter types of a function using [`function_traits` from the Boost.TypeTraits library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/function_traits.html).

To fully enable your described scenario of having what is effectively a variadic function that is type safe, you really need variadic templates, a new feature being added in C++0x and supported by some recently released compilers (e.g., Clang, gcc).  If you need something more extensive, you will probably need to implement your own runtime type system.

Comment: Although I have selected this answer as the correct answer, I have yet to figure out how to make `function_traits` work with functions rather than just their types (e.g. passing in `function_traits<SomeFunction>` rather than `function_traits<void (void)>`)

Comment: I have figured it out. Please see edits in my original question. Thanks to James for suggesting this, exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear what you're after, but [boost](http://www.boost.org/).[function_types](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/function_types/index.html) can tell you the return type, number of arguments, and argument types of a function pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using the [Boost::Function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/function.html) library and [Boost::TypeTraits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/function_traits.html). I find Boost::Function makes function pointers easier to deal with and allows you to use function objects in a generic way (i.e. you are not constrained by the type of the function object which is a pain), which are all round much nicer than raw function pointers

Answer (score 0):

You could probably convert [doxygen xml output](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_xml_output) into the proper declarations/metadata for your scripting language.  The information in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3842880/103167) might get you started.  Otherwise [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) might help you, it's designed for generating cross-language wrappers, and can probably generate them compatible with your scripting language of choice.